# traits difference between writing member as Trait or Trait() ex x=Str or x=Str()

Tags: python-2.7, enthought, traitsui

```
from traits.api import Str
class Foo(HasTraits):
    a=Str
    b=Str()
```

Is there any behavioral difference between members 'a' and 'b'?

Are trait attributes always instance specific or can they be class members?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. `MetaHasTraits` (the metaclass behind `HasTraits`) will happily consume either form and implicitly instantiate the former without arguments.

Trait attributes are always instance attributes, not class attributes.

Comment: That being said, I just found "add_class_trait()" :  http://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/advanced.html#add-class-trait

Comment: In the same line of questioning, if 'a' is a member of a class, is there a difference between a=MyClass() and a=Instance(MyClass) and a=Instance(MyClass,())  ?

Comment: @user3391229 That should be a new question, not a comment.

Comment: `add_class_trait()` is a `@classmethod` that will add a trait to a class such that all instances of that class will now have that trait as an instance attribute. This contrasts with `add_trait()` which is an `instancemethod` that adds the trait only to the instance you called it on and not other instances of the same class. In either case, the trait defines an instance attribute and not class attributes.